# Inserting particular XElement at specific position in a XML using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

string **myTagData** = "some valid xml data";

I want to write the LINQ to XML Query that can convert XML1 and XML2 to resultant XML1 and resultant XML2 , if abc tag exists then insert the content of **myTagData** as last child of abc tag otherwise if abc tag doesn't exist add **myTagData** content as last child of Root Element.

XML1

```
<data>
  <abc>
    <tag1></tag1>
    <tag2></tag2>
  </abc>     
</data>
```

XML2

```
<data>

<data>
    <cde>  
    </cde>
    <xyz>
    </xyz>   
</data>
```

Resultant xml 1

```
<data>
      <abc>
        <tag1></tag1>
        <tag2></tag2>
        <myTag></myTag>
      </abc>
      <bcd>
      </bcd>         
    </data>
```

Resultant XML2

```
<data>
    <cde>  
    </cde>
    <xyz>
    </xyz> 
    <myTag></myTag>   
</data>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy. Assuming you've got a variable `data` representing the `<data>` element, and `myTagData` is an element you want to add:

```
XContainer whereToAdd = data.Element("abc") ?? (XContainer) data;
whereToAdd.Add(myTagData);
```

That's using the null-coalescing operator as an easy way of switching between the two options... because the `Element` method returns null if the requested element doesn't exist. If you're not comfortable with the null-coalescing operator, you *may* find this simpler to understand:

```
XElement abc = data.Element("abc");
if (abc != null)
{
    abc.Add(myTagData);
}
else
{
    data.Add(myTagData);
}
```

Personally I refer the concise version though :)

Comment: I understands null-coalescing operator - courtesy (C# in Depth ) :)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: Excellent - glad to hear it :) (It can be a very handy little operator...)

Comment: @Joon Skeet,  Visual Studio is reporting that --- Error : Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type System.Xml.Linq.XElement and System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.--- Because data is of type XDocument and abc is of type XElement :( . So i will stay with Second approach

Comment: Sorry for extra chars in your name Stackoverflow wasn't allow me to type your name :)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: Just cast `data` to `XContainer` - will edit to show that. (It wasn't clear what type `data` would be.)